# How to solve error in opening zip file on .CAP file

Tags: java, javacard, verifyerror, cap

I want to verify a cap file using cmd on windows with

> verifycap.bat

tool.
I used the following command:

```
C:\Users\Mohammad\Desktop\VERIFY CAP\verifycap\bin>verifycap.bat imp.exp imp.cap > imp.hash
```

but the following exception error occurs:
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in the opening zip file

Can anyone help me with resolving this error, please?

Comment: Could you try what happens if you try that command in e.g. `C:\Temp`? I can remember something to do with special path names and such.

Comment: could you explain more clearly?

Comment: you have a long path name that involves spaces